# How to rebuild or recompile Libraries?

Tags: react-native

If I modify `Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource.js` something like below

```
function assetToImageSource(asset): ResolvedAssetSource {
  var devServerURL = getDevServerURL();

  if(devServerURL){
    console.log("devServerURL:"+getPathOnDevserver(devServerURL, asset));
  }else{
    console.log("PathInArchive:"+getPathInArchive(asset));
  }

  return {
    __packager_asset: true,
    width: asset.width,
    height: asset.height,
    uri: devServerURL ? getPathOnDevserver(devServerURL, asset) :   getPathInArchive(asset),
    scale: pickScale(asset.scales, PixelRatio.get()),
  };
}
```

How to rebuild or recompile Libraries ? and then I can see the console log from resolveAssetSource.js

Answer (score 3):

You don't need rebuild them, [react-native packager](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/packager) will do that. Just stop the packager and restart it. (Maybe you need [clean cache](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1924))

Comment: thanks,I WILL try,I have voted,but I have not 15 rep.

Comment: After ./packager/packager.sh --reset-cache, it works!Thanks again.

Comment: @Fomahaut: The link to react-native packager does not work anymore.